# How to turn a boolean array into index array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there an efficient Numpy mechanism to retrieve the integer indexes of locations in an array based on a condition is true as opposed to the Boolean mask array?

For example:

```
x=np.array([range(100,1,-1)])
#generate a mask to find all values that are a power of 2
mask=x&(x-1)==0
#This will tell me those values
print x[mask]
```

In this case, I'd like to know the indexes `i` of `mask` where `mask[i]==True`.  Is it possible to generate these without looping?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Another option:

```
In [13]: numpy.where(mask)
Out[13]: (array([36, 68, 84, 92, 96, 98]),)
```

which is the same thing as `numpy.where(mask==True)`.

Comment: Or similarly if you always have one-dimensional arrays: `numpy.flatnonzero(mask)`

Answer (score 37):

You should be able to use [`numpy.nonzero()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) to find this information.

Comment: use numpy.nonzero()[0]
otherwise you get two arrays. One with indices and one with values. If you want to use the indices to continue, this is easier. It only gives you an array with the indices.

Comment: @FloridaMan: `numpy.nonzero` does not give a tuple with an array of values as the second component. The tuple is used in case the Boolean array is multidimensional. From the docs: “Returns a tuple of arrays, one for each dimension […]”.

Answer (score 2):

```
np.arange(100,1,-1)
array([100,  99,  98,  97,  96,  95,  94,  93,  92,  91,  90,  89,  88,
        87,  86,  85,  84,  83,  82,  81,  80,  79,  78,  77,  76,  75,
        74,  73,  72,  71,  70,  69,  68,  67,  66,  65,  64,  63,  62,
        61,  60,  59,  58,  57,  56,  55,  54,  53,  52,  51,  50,  49,
        48,  47,  46,  45,  44,  43,  42,  41,  40,  39,  38,  37,  36,
        35,  34,  33,  32,  31,  30,  29,  28,  27,  26,  25,  24,  23,
        22,  21,  20,  19,  18,  17,  16,  15,  14,  13,  12,  11,  10,
         9,   8,   7,   6,   5,   4,   3,   2])

x=np.arange(100,1,-1)

np.where(x&(x-1) == 0)
(array([36, 68, 84, 92, 96, 98]),)
```

Now rephrase this like :

```
x[x&(x-1) == 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer the **indexer** way, you can convert your boolean list to numpy array:

```
print x[nd.array(mask)]
```