# Remove elements from a list that occur in another list and return their indices

Tags: python, algorithm, list

This `list`, for example:

```
my_list = ['a', 'd', 'a', 'd', 'c','e']
words_2_remove = ['a', 'c']
```

the output should then be:

```
my_list = ['d', 'd', 'e']
loc = [0, 2, 4]
```

I am currently using this:

```
loc = []    
for word in my_list:  
    if word in words_2_remove:
         loc.append( my_list.index(word) )
         my_list.remove(word)
```

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Better in which sense?

Comment: @Georgy Better could be more efficient, or flexible. For example, one might need to find the complement of the indices `loc`; then, he can just add `not` to the provided code below, something like:  `loc = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x not in words_2_remove]`

Answer (score 3):

Do two list-comprehensions:

```
my_list =['a', 'd', 'a', 'd', 'c','e']
words_2_remove = ['a', 'c']

loc = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x in words_2_remove]

my_list = [x for x in my_list if x not in words_2_remove]

print(my_list) # ['d', 'd', 'e']
print(loc)     # [0, 2, 4]
```

Comment: the fourth line can be replaced with `my_list = [my_list[i] for i in loc]`

Comment: @innuendo No, that gives you the opposite - All items in `my_list` that are also in `words_2_remove`.

Answer (score 1):

For bigger arrays using NumPy will be more efficient:

```
import numpy as np


my_list = np.array(['a', 'd', 'a', 'd', 'c','e'])
words_2_remove = np.array(['a', 'c'])

mask = np.isin(my_list, words_2_remove, invert=True)
# mask will be [False  True False  True False  True]
loc = np.where(~mask)[0]

print(loc)
>>> [0 2 4]

print(my_list[mask])
>>> ['d' 'd' 'e']
```

And it's also pretty easy to get the complement of the `loc` indices:

```
print(np.where(mask)[0])
>>> [1 3 5]
```

---

**Timings:**
Comparing with list comprehensions version from @Austin.
For original arrays:

```
my_list = np.array(['a', 'd', 'a', 'd', 'c','e'])
words_2_remove = np.array(['a', 'c'])

%%timeit
mask = np.isin(my_list, words_2_remove, invert=True)
loc = np.where(~mask)[0]
>>> 11 µs ± 53.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

my_list =['a', 'd', 'a', 'd', 'c','e']
words_2_remove = ['a', 'c']

%%timeit
loc = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x in words_2_remove]
res = [x for x in my_list if x not in words_2_remove]
>>> 1.31 µs ± 7.17 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

And for big arrays:

```
n = 10 ** 3
my_list = np.array(['a', 'd', 'a', 'd', 'c','e'] * n)
words_2_remove = np.array(['a', 'c'])

%%timeit
mask = np.isin(my_list, words_2_remove, invert=True)
loc = np.where(~mask)[0]
>>> 114 µs ± 906 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

my_list =['a', 'd', 'a', 'd', 'c','e'] * n
words_2_remove = ['a', 'c']

%%timeit
loc = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x in words_2_remove]
res = [x for x in my_list if x not in words_2_remove]
>>> 841 µs ± 677 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Depending on the use case, you can choose what fits better.

---

**Further reading:**

Docs on `np.isin`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html
Converting boolean mask array to indices: [How to turn a boolean array into index array in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218032/how-to-turn-a-boolean-array-into-index-array-in-numpy)
Docs on `np.where`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html
More on indexing with NumPy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Answer (score 0):

Using *list comprehension* and *enumerate*

```
loc = [idx for idx, item in enumerate(my_list) if item in words_2_remove]
my_list = [i for i in my_list if i not in words_2_remove]
```

Or using *filter*:

```
my_list = list(filter(lambda x: x not in words_2_remove, my_list))
```

Expanded Explanation:

```
loc = []
new_my_list = []
for idx, item in enumerate(my_list):
    if item in words_2_remove:
        loc.append(idx)
    else:
        new_my_list.append(item)
```

Comment: @Austin what you talking about its `not` there! :)

Comment: Well, I can see even if it's `not` there! Lol.