# what exactly is np.where(mask_array) returning?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a boolean array, from which I want to get the index values of all the True elements in that bool array. I read [this answer on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218032/how-to-turn-a-boolean-array-into-index-array-in-numpy) which suggested using `np.where(mask)`. In their answer the tuple that was returned contained only the indices and had 1 empty entry. In the case below I seem to also get a array of 0s. Why? Also I cant find what the default entries are in the documentation so I have no idea what `np.where(mask)` is actually doing. Normally I thought you need to pass both a condition and values to yield where condition is true and where its false, what is the condition here and what is it returning?

Code:

```
import numpy as np 

x = np.arange(9)
mask  = [x%3==0]
print('mask:',mask)
true_ixs = np.where(mask)
print('trueixs:',true_ixs)
```

Output:

```
mask: [array([ True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False])]
trueixs: (array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 3, 6]))
```

Comment: There's no default entry, but look carefully at the shapes of your arrays.

Comment: ahh i didnt catch that thanks!

Comment: `np.argwhere` applies `np.transpose` to that to produce a 2d array of indices.  Same values, just layed out differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) says:

> The function that is called when x and y are omitted: [np.nonzero](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero)